# Looping through elements with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to store some data that's scraped from a website. The data I need is the text from the element, to then store in a csv for querying later on.

In the code below, I'm finding all references to the class 'vip'. Then I want to loop through those to strip away the unnecessary HTML to get the text data only. Finally I encode it with utf-8, ready to be inserted into a csv.

```
# parse the page and store in var soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# find the title
title_box = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'vip'}}

print title_box

# loop through each iteration
for each in title_box:
    if each.find('title_box'):
        title = title_box.text.strip().encode('utf-8')

# print the result
print title
```

However whenever I print the result of 'title' I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/XXXX/Projects/project-kitchenaid/scaper.py", line 28, in <module>
    print title
NameError: name 'title' is not defined
```

From what I understand, `title` is out of scope. How do I retrieve the the data from the loop and write it to a print call?

For context, this is just one result of `print title_box`:

```
<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/KITCHENAID-CLASSIC-MIXER-5K45SS-ATTACHMENTS-AND-INSTRUCTIONS-/302468759209?hash=item466c8afea9:g:2PIAAOSwCi9Zvk2D" title="Click this link to access KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS">KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS</a>]
```

Comment: Your title variable is only defined when `each.find("title_box")` returns anything. This means that `title_box` was not found in any of the iterations.

Comment: What does `each.find('title_box')` do?

Comment: Ah I see, what I'm trying to do is extract each iteration of the data from the html with `('a', attrs={'class': 'vip'})`

Comment: Passing a string to `find` method searches for the tag whose name matches the string. So, when you call `each.find('title_box')`, you're trying to find a `title_box` tag. Are you sure that's what you want? If it's the value of a `class` attribute, you should use `each.find(attrs={'class': 'title_box'})`.

Comment: Mahesh that's correct, what I'm looking for would be this `if each.find('a', attrs={'class': 'vip'})`, so my question is this: How to I print those results from the loop and if/else statement?

Comment: How did the line `title = title_box.text.strip().encode('utf-8')` inside your for loop run without any error? By the time this line is executed, `title_box contains the list of `a` elements you extracted using the `findAll` method. So, this line should've raised an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps:

1. `title_box = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'vip'})`
   This line finds all the html having tag **"a"** and to further filter it using the required class **vip**.
2. You cannot do `if each.find('title_box'):` because there is no html tag called `title_box`
3. You can get the text using

   `for each in soup: print(each.text.strip().encode('utf-8'))`

No need to further use any conditional statements taking in reference the above extract

Answer (score 1):

I made an HTML file consisting of five copies of your `a` element and called it 'temp.htm':

```
<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/KITCHENAID-CLASSIC-MIXER-5K45SS-ATTACHMENTS-AND-INSTRUCTIONS-/302468759209?hash=item466c8afea9:g:2PIAAOSwCi9Zvk2D" title="Click this link to access KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS">KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS</a>
<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/KITCHENAID-CLASSIC-MIXER-5K45SS-ATTACHMENTS-AND-INSTRUCTIONS-/302468759209?hash=item466c8afea9:g:2PIAAOSwCi9Zvk2D" title="Click this link to access KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS">KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS</a>
<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/KITCHENAID-CLASSIC-MIXER-5K45SS-ATTACHMENTS-AND-INSTRUCTIONS-/302468759209?hash=item466c8afea9:g:2PIAAOSwCi9Zvk2D" title="Click this link to access KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS">KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS</a>
<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/KITCHENAID-CLASSIC-MIXER-5K45SS-ATTACHMENTS-AND-INSTRUCTIONS-/302468759209?hash=item466c8afea9:g:2PIAAOSwCi9Zvk2D" title="Click this link to access KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS">KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS</a>
<a class="vip" href="http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/KITCHENAID-CLASSIC-MIXER-5K45SS-ATTACHMENTS-AND-INSTRUCTIONS-/302468759209?hash=item466c8afea9:g:2PIAAOSwCi9Zvk2D" title="Click this link to access KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS">KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS</a>
```

Then I ran this code to get the texts in those links:

```
>>> page = open('temp.htm').read()
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> for link in soup.select('.vip'):
...     link.text
... 
'KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS'
'KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS'
'KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS'
'KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS'
'KITCHENAID CLASSIC MIXER 5K45SS - ATTACHMENTS AND INSTRUCTIONS'
```

You might still need to encode these texts for deposit in your csv file.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, using `each.find('title_box')` won't fetch you anything, because there's no `title_box` tag.

<del>Since you need the `a` elements with a `class` attribute of `vip`, this is what you should be checking for:</del>

```
if 'vip' in each['class']:
```

Also, when this line of your code runs:

```
title_box = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'vip'}}
```

the `title_box` list is already populated with `a` elements that have a `class` attribute of `vip`. So, you don't have to check the same condition again in the for loop.

This is the code you should try:

```
for each in title_box:
    title = each.text.strip().encode('utf-8')
    print title
```

Of course, you can do away with assigning the text to a variable altogether and print it directly:

```
print each.text.strip().encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: That's what I thought but the console returns nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see the bottom of the question where the extract is.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to be careful with the variable "title" scope.

Try this:

```
# parse the page and store in var soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# find the title
title_box = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'vip'}}

print(title_box)

# loop through each iteration

for each in title_box:
    if each.find('title_box'):
        title = title_box.text.strip().encode('utf-8')
        # print the result
        print(title)
```

or, in case you want to store all the results

```
# parse the page and store in var soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# find the title
title_box = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'vip'}}

print(title_box)

# loop through each iteration
title_list=[]
for each in title_box:
    if each.find('title_box'):
         title_list.append(title_box.text.strip().encode('utf-8'))

# print the results
for title in title_list:
       print(title)
```